# Simple SSH/Git pull continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up Atlassian Bamboo trying to get a minimal build plan off the ground. Our current set up is pretty basic. We have several projects that we git clone onto either a stage or a prod server. Currently when we want to deploy we ssh into the correct host, navigate to the directory where the project lives and pull down the changes manually.

Bamboo has an SSH task, but it only allows you to execute one command on that ssh task. I need to run `cd /www/stage/project_dir` and then `git pull origin master`. Can someone point me in the right direction in setting this up?

Comment: Do you need to execute these commands on a remote machine? Or on the bamboo server it self?

Comment: On a remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still [an open ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12298) to get the enhancement you want.

To elaborate on Adurbe's answer:
You could drop a .sh file onto your server and then call it via Bamboo. Check out this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine) question and look over the answers to find what will be best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the ticket link. Even though it isn't what I wanted to hear it answers the question well.

Answer (score 0):

could you not run a batch file/shell script on the server that contains the two commands?

Comment: Although the answer might be correct, maybe you can give a bit more context and example how this would work in combination with Bamboo? The SE QA format works better with well defined answers.

Comment: I suppose I could, but I was hoping that there might be a way to specify those steps within Bamboo itself. If the process changes I'd like to just update the plan and not have to worry about updating scripts.